# Linux firefox and flash player settings for permission for camera and voice not displayed, but works in windows

Tags: linux, firefox, apache-flex, flex4.5, flash

We are developing video chat application in flex 4.5 and php, when we run this application in browser run under flash player in browser, and ask the settings popup for permissions for camera and audio device, it works fine under windows and i am able to grant permission and do chat.

but when I run this over Linux(Ubuntu) Firefox( version 25) , no popup display for permissions in Linux.

when I run same application under Linux in chrome browser, it works.

help me resolve the issue of flash player settings popup not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar problem often occurs on Windows: the permissions popup is displayed and then the swf movie just hangs.

A workaround would be to ask the users to visit [the Website Privacy Settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html) before using your application and permanently allow your domain to access the webcam and microphone.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for suggesting, this works, but what i need the pop to be displayed in all the browser, and I am still looking for this issue.